# Not getting Customer details on Home Page, Category page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento-2.1, magento2.1.0

I am tring to get currently logged in Customer Detail Using below Code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerData = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getData();  
print_r($customerData);
```

I am Getting desired result on account page `/customer/account/`, Result as below

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 2
    [website_id] => 1
    [email] => email@example.com
    [group_id] => 1
    [increment_id] => 
    [store_id] => 1
    [created_at] => 2016-07-20 10:22:23
    [updated_at] => 2016-08-08 05:21:25
    [is_active] => 1
    [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
    [created_in] => Default Store View
    [prefix] => 
    [firstname] => Firstname
    [middlename] => 
    [lastname] => Lastname
    [suffix] => 
    [dob] => 
    [password_hash] => 94f205d......
    [rp_token] => f35c6ff1.....
    [rp_token_created_at] => 2016-07-20 10:22:24
    [default_billing] => 
    [default_shipping] => 
    [taxvat] => 
    [confirmation] => 
    [gender] => 
    [failures_num] => 0
    [first_failure] => 
    [lock_expires] => 
)
```

But not getting correct result on Homepage, category page, product page etc., Result as below

```
Array ( 
    [group_id] => 1 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get customerId from customer session and then you can load customer details.

```
$customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
$customer = $this->customerFactory->create()->load($customerId);
```